# what is the difference between 'of sth' and 'sth'

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

For example:

> Of special interest is the method.

- what's the sentence mean?
- Is it similar to **Special interest is the method**.

Comment: No. *Special interest is the method* isn't really a meaningful / valid utterance (unless it's in some weird context where "Special Interest" is a known way of doing things, but I don't know of any such). The initial *(**valid**)* utterance ***Of special interest is the method*** is simply a stylised resequencing of the more normal sentence ***The method is of special interest*** (where ***of special interest*** is just another way of saying ***[e]specially / particularly interesting***).

Comment: The same principle applies to ***of*** regardless of whether the text features that stylised resequencing / inversion or not. That's to say, you must include the preposition where ***of** special interest* adjectivally modifies ***the method***. But where "the method" is being ***equated*** to something, you don't want a preposition, so it's *The method is Bayesian inference*, OR *Bayesian inference is the method.*

Comment: I simplify the sentence, the complete sentence is **Of special interest is the errorMessage method of ArgsException.**. which I really want to know is what the difference is when putting **of** ahead of **special interest**.

Comment: Syntactically, the difference is that "special interest" on its own would be a ***noun phrase***, whereas "**of** special interest" is an ***adjectival*** construction. But it's not easy to create a natural context using "special interest" as a noun phrase (that could function as the syntactic ***subject*** of a sentence), so I suggest you think through the relevant syntax with single-word "value" - which works just the same. Thus *The errorMessage method of ArgsException **is of value*** (it's ***useful***), which can be "inverted" ("fronting") to ***Of value** is the errorMessage method...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of *fronting* to make something the topic.

Syntactically, it is equivalent to

> The method is of special interest.

You need "of", because the method is not itself "interest" - that is a property which is attached to the method, for the purposes of the current discourse.